# When searching for "$", how do I make Solr highlight only "$" when indexed content is "$1),"?

Tags: solr, highlighting

I'm having a problem with highlighting.

I've set up Solr to return the the entire contents of a particular field.  **That part works just fine,** i.e., the entire contents of the field are being returned with the results.  What is **not** working is highlighting a particular portion of the field contents.

The field contains `$1),`.  With analyzers, I'm stripping out the parenthesis and the comma, and breaking off the dollar sign into its own word, leaving `$ 1`.  In analysis.jsp, I use `$1),` as the index value, and `$` as the query value, and it matches `$` successfully.  When I re-index and hit the select handler URL, though, the highlighted part remains `<em>$1),</em>`.

How do I ensure that the only part of `$1),` that is actually highlighted is `$`, i.e., `<em>$</em>1),` ?

To be clear, I'm getting this `<em>$1),</em>`, but I really want this `<em>$</em>1),`.

I'm using Solr 3.6 with FastVectorHighlighting and SingleFragListBuilder.  Per advice on here, I've tried using the default highlighter but couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: It seems like the tokenization might have something to do with it, i.e., if I were to use a tokenizer that strips out the characters I don't want, rather than using a post-tokenization filter, then that might get the highlighter to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify your solrconfig.xml according to [this wiki section](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragsize) and tell solr the size of the highlighted snippet. i never tried it with 1, but it should work (we're highlighting words with 3 or more characters, and with 3 works fine, so i guess it's the same for 1)

Comment: Hmm. . . .  I thought that had to do with the content that was returned by the highlighter, not what was actually highlighted.

Comment: I'm trying adding `&hl.fragsize=1` but don't see a change.  We're also using `fragListBuilder=single`.  Think that would cause a conflict?

Comment: did you try to modify the snippet size inside solrconfig.xml? often the solution is there

Comment: I did.  Seems like if you use FastVectorHighlighting then those parameters don't change anything.